# How can I request to stack overflow to add new TAG for new technology?

Tags: support, tags, tag-search

I know that to add new TAG it require some high amount of reputation. But is there any other way. I have marked many time that people are not getting proper answers and question views because of tags not available and those people are new to stack-overflow so not able to add tag.

Any help would appreciate.

Comment: Exactly what tag(s) are you wanting?

Comment: I want tags : Oxwall , Oxwall-plugins , Oxwall-themes , Responsive-oxwall , skadate , skadate-themes  etc.

Comment: There are [27 results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=oxwall) with the word `oxwall` in them. How many of them actually need the tag, and how many simply mention the product?

Comment: As oxwall tag is not available people have to use php tag there. I really do not know are they need oxwall as tag or not but i feel that oxwall really needed so just asked here. Is there any chance to add that tag?

Comment: Having 27 questions at most certainly means that you might need _one_ "Oxwall" tag, but not the three specific ones. What use is a tag that either appears on all questions or just on one or two of them?

Comment: @l4mpi - Means? I am not getting you. If we add tag then people will use it surely.

Comment: We don't want tags for every single corner of a technology specially if there are at the moment only 27 relevant questions. Start with one major tag. If it beomes a mess we can correct later....

Comment: @HelpingHands generally speaking, the guidelines for add tags assumes the questions exist first and the tag is added to fit the existing need.  We can't create tags without questions - in fact tags without any questions will be deleted daily.  So add the tag that is needed and then when the need arrises to add more, we can add them then.

Comment: What is there to get? You have at most 27 questions about Oxwall, you certainly don't need _four_ tags for specific things such as "Oxwall-plugins". Same with "skadate", there are currently only 8 questions about it. We certainly don't need a "skadate-themes" tag as it would not provide a meaningful categorization with so few questions.

Comment: @l4mpi - I understand everything . I need only 1 tag called "oxwall" if other are not OK with you.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - I know that but people like me do not have that level reputation so we can not add tag when going to add question related to oxwall. Thats why I am asking here that what is solution?

Comment: Link to a couple of good on-topic question that you think deserve/need the Oxwall tag. Then we can decide. Note that not everything which contains the world "Oxwall" necessarily needs such a tag.

Comment: @HelpingHands asking on Meta is fine... the problem is you can't create tags without questions, so asking for 3 tags with the hope that if the tags exist, people will ask questions is not the right approach.  You need to identify the need and find questions that would fit.  If there are enough, then the tag is probably needed,  If not, then it probably isn't.

Comment: Ok everyone I understood things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are going to have to do a better job of selling this if you want someone to create the tag.

27 mentions over the space of two years is hardly a high volume of questions. However it gets worse - in a totally unscientific random* sampling of 7 questions:

- 4 only mentioned Oxwall in some tangential way, it wasn't the main subject ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25217469/109702), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18804817/109702), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13943161/109702), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19092451/109702) )
- 2 were instantly down voted and close voted for being poor quality ( [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21661414/109702), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27140094/109702) )
- [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14033950/109702) actually had something to do with configuring Oxwall itself

If no higher rep users have seen the need to add a tag yet, I wouldn't be rushing off to do it myself based on those results. I would also doubt that people are not getting good search results due to the tag not being applied - the Stack Exchange search searches for the entered terms by default, unless you codify them in a specific way to change their meaning. Therefore if people search for Oxwall they should get it.

*Based on the small list it wasn't so random, it was 7 questions in a row.

Comment: I am suggesting to add list.js, refer http://www.listjs.com/, a Tiny, invisible and simple, yet powerful and incredibly fast vanilla JavaScript that adds search, sort, filters and flexibility to plain HTML lists, tables, or anything. The request is regarding to question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30119551/disappearing-list-items-when-sorting-searching-w-list-js/30121174#30121174. The tag should be list.js not list.